# Excel workbooks are opening up in separate instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, worksheet-function

I want my workbooks in one instance, otherwise I cannot easily reference other open workbooks in formulas.

My first impression was that it was Google Chrome's fault. It seemed like newly-downloaded excel or csv files that I opened from Chrome's downloads toolbar were being opened up in separate instances.

But just now, I tried to do a VLOOKUP between two xlsx files and I could not, because clicking on the VLOOKUP table range in file #2 changes focus to file #2 instead of filling in the table range reference in file #1's formula.

I suspect this is coming from a recent Excel update.

Windows 8.1. Excel 365.

EDIT:
Per suggestion, I checked registry value change in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default), but there is no such change. There's no DWORD key at all in my registry at that location.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options`

The linked instructions show a slightly different path, but I assume that "HKCU" is just an abbreviation for "HKEY_CURRENT_USER".

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options`

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165211/how-to-force-excel-to-open-in-a-new-instance-by-default

Comment: @TonyStewart I've never followed the instructions in your link so my workbooks should not be opening in separate instances, and I do not want them to open in separate instances. Your link is for people who want their workbooks to open in separate instances. In fact, the very first sentence in my question starts with "I want my workbooks in one instance."

Comment: I assumed you could check if an update did that or if you have updates including the ones references or assert the same =0  doh

Comment: @TonyStewart I guess I should have mentioned that I tried searching Google about my problem and found that exact same link. Most people have the opposite problem as me, apparently. I didn't check before, but I'm checking now and there is no indication of the change in my registry. ;)

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.exe\shell\open\command  "C:\Program Files....excel.exe"  "%1"       Remove "%1" from the end of the Command Line and add [open("%1")] for the DDE message.?? or get Filetypesman.exe and search for offending file type.  Cant do vlookup on csv files